# Working link for Google Cloud pipeline components docs?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubeflow-pipelines, google-cloud-ai-platform-pipelines, google-cloud-vertex-ai

Does anyone have a working link for the docs for Google Cloud pipeline components. The link in the [github page](https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/tree/master/components/google-cloud) under "ReadTheDocs page" is broken. Tried some other tutorial notebooks, such as [this one](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ai-platform-samples/blob/master/ai-platform-unified/notebooks/official/pipelines/google-cloud-pipeline-components_automl_images.ipynb), the link under "The components are documented here." seems to be broken too.

Edit:

The [link](https://google-cloud-pipeline-components.readthedocs.io/en/google-cloud-pipeline-components-0.1.4/) is up now.

Comment: their build is failing. You can either contribute the fix or you can clone the repo and build it yourself

Answer (score -1):

Pipelines support KFP (Kubeflow pipeline) and TFX (Tensorflow Extended) definitions. You have documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/pipelines/run-pipeline#kubeflow-pipelines-sdk)

You can find useful resources [here](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/pipelines/build-pipeline#tutorials) especially this [notebook](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ai-platform-samples/blob/master/ai-platform-unified/notebooks/official/pipelines/pipelines_intro_kfp.ipynb)